# Pinecone with Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, vector-database

I am trying to index documents (vector embeddings) in Azure Databricks and save/query the indexes afterwards using Pinecone. I am following the examples using:

https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/databricks

They seem quite clear, and I can initialize and query my index in Pinecone. The problem, however, is saving the index to Pinecone in the first place. My code is similar to the what is presented in the examples (I have the embeddings in `df`):

```
df.write \
  .option("pinecone.apiKey", "...") \
  .option("pinecone.environment", "...") \
  .option("pinecone.projectName", "...") \
  .option("pinecone.indexName", "...") \
  .format("io.pinecone.spark.pinecone.Pinecone") \
  .mode("append") \
  .save()
```

I have double-checked that my options are correct. I am getting an aborted job, and looking at the stack trace, I can see:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o493.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.writingJobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ExistingTableWriteExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2ExistingTableWriteExec.run$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:590)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:590)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.2.200.4 executor driver): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder
    at io.pinecone.PineconeConnection.buildChannel(PineconeConnection.java:89)
    at io.pinecone.PineconeConnection.<init>(PineconeConnection.java:44)
    at io.pinecone.PineconeClient.connect(PineconeClient.java:37)
    at io.pinecone.spark.pinecone.PineconeDataWriter.<init>(PineconeDataWriter.scala:27)
    at io.pinecone.spark.pinecone.PineconeDataWriterFactory.createWriter(PineconeDataWriterFactory.scala:10)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:832)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:835)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:690)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3088)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3035)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3029)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3029)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3297)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3238)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3226)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2657)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:371)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder
    at io.pinecone.PineconeConnection.buildChannel(PineconeConnection.java:89)
    at io.pinecone.PineconeConnection.<init>(PineconeConnection.java:44)
    at io.pinecone.PineconeClient.connect(PineconeClient.java:37)
    at io.pinecone.spark.pinecone.PineconeDataWriter.<init>(PineconeDataWriter.scala:27)
    at io.pinecone.spark.pinecone.PineconeDataWriterFactory.createWriter(PineconeDataWriterFactory.scala:10)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:832)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:835)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:690)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

My environment:

- Compute: 11.3 ML (no GPU though)
- Library: pinecone-client (PyPI)
- Library: io.pinecone:spark-pinecone_2.12:0.1.1 (Maven)

I think the class in question is in the `grpc-netty` package, but I can confirm at least references to that package in Databricks JARs (I believe version `1.45.x`).

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: please post bigger stacktrace. It could be that class is called with incorrect arguments, or something like that